Is there any way of finding out if the main() function of your program has been entered yet?
I'm having some issues with static initialization order fiasco. I have a class that should not be instantiated/constructed before my program enters main. This is because when the program enters main all static initialisation has been completed. Obviously a simple answer is just don't instantiate/construct/initialise an object of that type as a static variable, but I want a check in case it happens accidentally and there's a bug I can't discover.
I thought about having a flag bHasEnteredMain that I can set as the first thing in main, but this doesn't help, because there's no initialization order and therefore that flag have the garbage equivalent to true at that memory, so it's of no use. Is there a way to do this? Is there an in-built flag or something like that in the C++ standard or the compiler that I can use as a check?

"This is because when the program enters main all static initialisation has been completed." -- Not necessarily, although at a guess (without seeing your code) it might be close enough for your purposes.

@JaMiT What do you mean by not necessarily? Isn't it guaranteed?

Found it: Is the static initialization of global variables completed before main()? (I did not, though, find the question I recall with an answer that nicely explained the difference between static initialization of static variables and dynamic initialization of static variables.)

@JaMiT From CPPReference: "All non-local variables with static storage duration are initialized as part of program startup, before the execution of the main function begins (unless deferred, see below)."         And the then the bit below refers to "deferred dynamic initialization". So in certain cases dynamic initialization may happen after main enters? This is so HARD. I just want this to make sense.

"This is so HARD. I just want this to make sense" -- Try addressing the specific problem rather than generalizing to "before my program enters main". Look into why this restriction exists. Try to detect the reason for the restriction instead of the start of main.

@JaMiT " Look into why this restriction exists. " -- Are you talking about dynamically loaded libraries? Other than that it would just be simpler if you said "All static initialisation happens before main()"

Can you place a breakpoint at main() and run your code with the debugger?

@Zebrafish "Are you talking about dynamically loaded libraries?" -- Not unless you're making one. The restriction I mentioned is the one you stated for your class. Why must your class not be instantiated before your program enters main? That is almost certainly an imprecise criterion, for the simple reason that there is no easy way to detect it.

You can have a global bool that is set to false, then you change it to true in your main.
Global trivial objects are initialized before the C++ runtime starts initializing non-trivial objects on many platforms.
another solution is to have a meyers' singleton equivalent of a counter, that you call at the start of main and in the constructor of the class that you want to not construct statically.
int count()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    return counter;
}

If this returns any number except 1 in main then it was called during static initialization and a static instance of the class exists !

Now what happens when the object is in another TU?

@NathanOliver it doesn't matter, the C++ runtime hasn't started yet, they are initialized by the dynamic linker while loading the application or shared object into memory.

@NathanOliver That's probably not relevant in this case, since this global variable is specifically for the use of by a particular class, so it should be declared in the same TU. It's not a general flag that you intend to use in many different libraries.

@Barmar The whole point of the static initialization order fiasco is that static objects in multiple TUs have no defined order.  Shouldn't that mean that multiple TUs are involved?  If this is all in one TU then there is no issue to begin with as each TU has a guaranteed total order.

@NathanOliver Then I suspect the OP was confused about undefined static initialization order, and thout it applied within the TU.

@Barmar I know it's defined within one TU. I meant across them.

So this solution works because built-in types like int and bool are initialised before user-defined types? Is that the reason?

@Zebrafish yes, at least on machines with an operating system the dynamic linker initializes those variables while it is doing things like code relocation, then the C++ runtime starts, for microcontrollers on the other hand i don't really know, but i know you can customize the initialization of microcontrollers.

You might need to add more details to your explanation of how you'd use count(), I can't understand how it would help

Function with a static flag inside (Meyers's singleton-like construct) is the way to go. Depending on what is needed, you can do it e.g. this way:
#include <iostream>

//yes, the interface is somewhat clunky
bool mainWasCalled(bool mark = false)
{
    static bool wasCalled{};
    if (!wasCalled && mark) {
        wasCalled = true;
    }
    return wasCalled;
}


struct S
{
    S() { std::cout << mainWasCalled() << '\n'; }
};

static S staticS;
S globalS;

int main()
{
    mainWasCalled(true);
    S localS;
}

Counter incremented in main also could work, pick the interface you like.
This works based on the following principle:
static object inside function prevents the static initialization order fiasco -- it is initialized the moment the function is entered. The fuction itself effectively manipulates (and returns) the state of a global variable.
The only problem might occur when your global objects will try to call this function from within multiple threads; you can possibly have a data race between main() and some other thread spawned before it's called.
demo
